# Filter list from multiple values

Tags: list, powershell, filtering

I have this line:

```
$output.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.ItemPath -notlike "*.zip" } | Select ItemPath
```

Example output:

```
ItemPath                                                    
--------                                                    
\\devws04                                                   
\\devws04\c$                                                
\\devws04\c$\share                                          
\\devws04\c$\share\Dieser ORdner ist offline erstellt worden
\\devws04\c$\share\FileOfflineMode - Copy.txt               
\\devws04\c$\share\FileOfflineMode.txt                      
\\devws04\c$\share\Personal                                 
\\devws04\c$\share\Personal\Okey Cuuus.txt                  
\\devws04\c$\share\Portfolio.txt
```

The line excludes path values which contain "*.zip". It works but I want to use a variable at this place and not append everything to the same line with "and".

I tried following:

```
$ignoreFiles = @("*.zip", "*.psd")
$output.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.ItemPath -notin $ignoreFiles } | Select ItemPath
```

And several other snippets but none of them worked. It did just nothing to the result. Any hint appreciated!

This is the full output:

```
ItemPath                                                                            
--------                                                                            
\\devws04                                                                           
\\devws04\c$                                                                        
\\devws04\c$\share                                                                  
\\devws04\c$\share\Dieser ORdner ist offline erstellt worden                        
\\devws04\c$\share\Dieser ORdner ist offline erstellt worden\MeineofflineDateien.zip
\\devws04\c$\share\FileOfflineMode - Copy.txt                                       
\\devws04\c$\share\FileOfflineMode.txt                                              
\\devws04\c$\share\Personal                                                         
\\devws04\c$\share\Personal\Okey Cuuus.txt                                          
\\devws04\c$\share\Portfolio.txt
```

EDIT:
This is the actual code and my goal is to do a csv-export but before I want to filter the values like described above:

```
$ignoreFiles = "\.zip|\.psd"
#$ignoreFiles = @("*.zip", "*.psd")
    $query = Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_OfflineFilesItem"
    $hostName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
    $user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
    $output = @()
    $query | ? {
    $output += [PSCustomObject] @{
            User = $user
            Hostname = $hostName
            ItemPath = $_.ItemPath 
        }
    } 

    $output  | Export-CSV $outputPath -NoTypeInformation # ONLY EXPORT OBJECTS WHERE $_.ItemPath does not contain one of the values from $ignoreFiles!
```

Comment: What is $output? Would you like to have just the paths returned or the full object?

Comment: yes, the full object it would be..

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: @Mötz that is fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please consider sharing the end result for other to learn from your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use regex to help you with the challenge that you face:

```
$regex = "\.zip|\.psd"
$paths = $output.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object ItemPath

$paths.ItemPath -notmatch $regex
```

**Updated with extra answer**

I would say this should do the trick

```
$output = $output | Where-Object {$_.ItemPath -notmatch $ignoreFiles }
$output  | Export-CSV $outputPath -NoTypeInformation # ONLY EXPORT OBJECTS WHERE $_.ItemPath does not contain one of the values from $ignoreFiles!
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well but I am looking for a solution without regex and that the definition for the ignoring values could stay like that: $ignoreFiles = @("*.zip", "*.psd")

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasoning for **not** wanting to utilize regex?

Comment: Cool - glad I could help. You could build your regex from an array of strings / extensions, if you fear the syntax if other people are to fill in the details in your scripts later.

Comment: Yes that was my thought :) I have one more question, how would I return the "object" itself but not the attribute "ItemPath"? I tried: $results = $output.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {
   ($_.ItemPath -notmatch $regex)
}

Comment: Because I want to do this: $output  | Export-CSV $outputPath -NoTypeInformation  and for this, I have to do all the filtering in a one-liner...

Comment: Update your question with the latest code you have built. Just add it as a new section. Then I'll have a look at it.

Comment: please check my code, I provided now all the full details.

Comment: If $output is the result of a [PSCustomObject] and not a hashtable, there is no need for the .GetEnumerator() method. Use `$paths = ($output | Where-Object ItemPath -notmatch $regex).ItemPath` as a shortcut instead of a `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ...`

Answer (score 0):

not sure what `$output` is,

But using a variable should work exactly the same:

```
$ext = "*.zip"
$output | Where-Object { $_.ItemPath -notlike $ext } | Select ItemPath
```

You could also use -notin for an array of things, depending on the input:

```
gci | Where-Object { $_.Extension -notin ($ext, ".7z") } | Select FullName
```

Comment: $ouput is just a [PSCustomObject], a list with objects with simple properties and attributes. Your snippets don't work. I want multiple excludes and not only ".zip".

Comment: @eMi Don't put additional information in various comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53658847/edit) your question to contain that information.

Comment: @eMi I'd need the method for creating the object then, if it's a single property you want to compare against an array of objects then we would want to do something different.

Comment: `$_.ItemPath -notlike "*$ext"` (note the wildcard character `*`).

Comment: @JosefZ yep! Although in the variable would likely be better. #updated

Comment: this still would not work. Why dont you try using an additional file extension in $ext?

Comment: @eMi it absolutely works for the first part of your question "***which contain "*.zip". It works but I want to use a variable at this place and not append everything to the same line with "and".***" without having the contents of your PSObject we can only guess with heavy handed and obtuse tools like regex and string matching.

Comment: @AustinTFrench please check my code, I provided now all the full details.

Comment: @eMi seeing as it's just a string, and a UNC path you could do a lot depending on if you want more readable or more performant. Based on that, I would probably use a regex as well, the alternatives being -split(".") and getting the extension manually and then a -contains or another custom method. None of which make sense for what appears to be a pretty small scoped script . I will leave the answer for posterity (your title might bring someone looking to solve a very different problem)